# Symfony Form Collection Theming but feed some data

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Symfony 3.3

I have a form of my Voyage entity

Voyage entity has a Collection in it, named cities, collection of entity City.
And so do the form with the Collection named cities.

The user first use the form and create an instance of Voyage and add some cities to it, I managed to customise the prototype and render it via javascript when the user click "add city" button.

The form is rendered this way for the interesting part (cleaned version without html):

```
{% extends "@User/layout.html.twig" %}
{% form_theme form.cities '@Prototype/city.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
   {{ form_start(form) }}
   {{ form_errors(form) }}
   {{ form_row(form.cities) }}
   {{ form_rest(form) }}
   {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock content %}
```

The theme for the 'form.cities' :

```
{% block collection_widget %}
{% import '@Prototype/prototype.city.twig' as proto %}
{% spaceless %}
<div class="collection">
    {% if prototype is defined %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': proto.city(prototype)|escape }) %}
    {% endif %}

    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}></div>
    <div id="container-cities">
    {# Here I will add the cities via javascript when user add one #}
    </div>
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock collection_widget %}
```

The macro file used in this theme and imported as proto :

```
{% macro city(widget, id, name, zip) %}
{% spaceless %}
<div 
    class="added-city border-gray" 
    data-id="{{id|default('__id__')}}"  
    id="{{name|default('__name__')}}">

    {{name|default('__city_name__')}} ({{zip|default('__zip__')}})
    {{ form_errors(widget) }}
    {{ form_widget(widget) }}
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

**My general problem :** When the user wants to edit its instance of Voyage, it already has some cities in it. How can I render them ? How can I access the cities variable from within the theme.

**My partial solution :** I wanted to extract the 'container-cities' block from the theme file to the rendered html where the form is initialy rendered and where I can access the variables and do this :

```
{% import '@Prototype/prototype.city.twig' as proto %}
{% for city in form.cities %}
{{ proto.city(city, city.name) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it give me this error :

```
Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()", "getname()"/"isname()"/"hasname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".
```

(It doesn't fail on city.id probably because of some other field named id)

**My question** :

- How can I access the cities within the theme and render them with my macro ?

Or

- How to access to the cities items where I render the form, because the form.cities doesn't seem to be the actual City entity Collection, and get rid of that error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, it was that simple :

I just used this in the form theme :

```
{% for city in form %}
{{ proto.city(city, city.vars.value.id, city.vars.value.name, city.vars.value.zip) }}
{% endfor %}
```